# How to add drawable image inside textview

Tags: android, textview

I need a drawable within the text, just like an emoji, so e.g.

"Please press the button looking like this  and then proceed ..."

but with a custom drawable instead of the emoji in my example. (How) is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

> I need a drawable within the text

You can Use [**`ImageSpan`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html)

- `Span` that replaces the text it's attached to with a `Drawable` that can be aligned with the bottom or with the baseline of the surrounding text. The `drawable` can be constructed from varied sources:

> but with a custom drawable instead of the emoji in my example. (How) is this possible?

Try this working example

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView  textView=findViewById(R.id.tv);
        Spannable span = new SpannableString("Please press the button looking like this and then proceed ..");
        Drawable test = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc);
        test.setBounds(0, 0, 32,32);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(test, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        span.setSpan(imageSpan, 36, 37, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        textView.setText(span);
    }


}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try unicode:

```
int unicode = 0x1F60A;
```

And use it like this:

```
public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){
    return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
}
```