# Insert Multiple images inside EditText

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on an app for deaf-mute people, so created a specific keyboard for the app. Now, I want to set images in an EditText, the images are symbols used by the deaf-mute people I want something like this :
[deaf-muet keyboard + EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyzDx.png)

in that editText, I was able to set only the first sign which it refers to the first letter, but I want to set many images for each letter.
I used the .setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() but it only gave me the first letter.
how can I do to set multiple images in an EditText or in ViewText?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625171/how-to-add-drawable-image-inside-textview/49625261#49625261

Comment: you need it inside edittext? you can put it to other layout, for example frame that will be on top of your edittext.

Comment: @VadimEksler can you plz expain more?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i Hope it will help you

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon">
</EditText>
```

The same thing you can try for:

```
android:drawableRight
android:drawableTop
android:drawableBottom
android:drawablePadding
```

Comment: this will let me just to add an icon to the EditText, but in my case the images should inserted when the user is writing in the editText

Answer (score 0):

this class is custom editText that you can use to put a drawable inside it.

```
public class WithIconEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
int actionX, actionY;
private Drawable drawableRight;
private Drawable drawableLeft;
private Drawable drawableTop;
private Drawable drawableBottom;
private DrawableClickListener clickListener;

public WithIconEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public WithIconEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top, Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
    if (left != null)
        drawableLeft = left;
    if (right != null)
        drawableRight = right;
    if (top != null)
        drawableTop = top;
    if (bottom != null)
        drawableBottom = bottom;
    super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
}

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Rect bounds;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        actionX = (int) event.getX();
        actionY = (int) event.getY();
        if (drawableBottom != null && drawableBottom.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
            clickListener.onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.BOTTOM);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        if (drawableTop != null && drawableTop.getBounds().contains(actionX, actionY)) {
            clickListener.onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.TOP);
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        if (drawableLeft != null) {
            bounds = drawableLeft.getBounds();
            int x, y;
            int extraTapArea = (int) (13 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5);
            x = actionX;
            y = actionY;
            if (!bounds.contains(actionX, actionY)) {
                x = actionX - extraTapArea;
                y = actionY - extraTapArea;
                if (x <= 0)
                    x = actionX;
                if (y <= 0)
                    y = actionY;
                if (x < y)
                    y = x;
            }
            if (bounds.contains(x, y) && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.LEFT);
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (drawableRight != null) {
            bounds = drawableRight.getBounds();
            int x, y;
            int extraTapArea = 13;
            x = actionX + extraTapArea;
            y = actionY - extraTapArea;
            x = getWidth() - x;
            if (x <= 0) {
                x += extraTapArea;
            }
            if (y <= 0)
                y = actionY;
            if (bounds.contains(x, y) && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onClick(DrawableClickListener.DrawablePosition.RIGHT);
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                return false;
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    drawableRight = null;
    drawableBottom = null;
    drawableLeft = null;
    drawableTop = null;
    super.finalize();
}

public void setDrawableClickListener(DrawableClickListener listener) {
    this.clickListener = listener;
}

public interface DrawableClickListener {
    void onClick(DrawablePosition target);

    enum DrawablePosition {TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT}
}
}
```

Comment: does this allow me to put multiple drawables in the EditText?

Comment: well, that's not what i am looking to, i want to set even more then four drawables in that EditText