# Views continued one after another Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have 3 views, 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView. I want the views to be aligned  one after another like below :-

Here the "+" sign is an ImageView and "Another Text" is the second TextView.
[image]

I tried using a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. Also RelativeLayout , but the First TextView shows  but the next ImageView and the TextView do not show.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            style="@style/style_ww"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtusername"
                style="@style/style_ww"
                android:text="jjjkcrhwkjehrckwjherkjwherckjwhekrcjwernwjkrncwjknrkwjncwjrnwkjcnkwjnrckwjnrkwjnrkwjcncrkjwnrkjcwnrnwkrcnkwnrkwnrckwjnrkwjncrknwkrjnckwnrkwjnrkcwnrkwnckjnrkwnrkwnrckwnrkwnrckwrn"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlueGrey400"
                android:textSize="@dimen/size_fourteen"
                app:fontFamily="@font/roboto"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/plus"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/value_2"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/value_2"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/value_1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tvcomment"
                style="@style/style_ww"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/value_5"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/value_20"
                android:text="@string/comment"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlueGrey400"
                app:fontFamily="@font/roboto"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

style/style_ww

```
<style name="style_ww">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: please show your code

Comment: @Bunny I have updated my code

Comment: please, show also the code of your style style_ww

Comment: @VictorSemenovich Check my update

Comment: @user3034944 check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49625171/how-to-add-drawable-image-inside-textview/49625261#49625261

Comment: @NileshRathod The example seems to insert the image after certain number of characters, but my first string is dynamic and I want the image only after the string ends

Comment: @user3034944 its very simple just add image at end of your image  (string.lenght)

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks for the tip. Also since I have two different strings unlike the example, how can I implement that with 2 different strings?

Comment: @user3034944 like this First use a `SpannableStringBuilder` add your first string in it than use `imagespan` to display image and append into `SpannableStringBuilder` and than append your second string into `SpannableStringBuilder`

Comment: @NileshRathod Can you please elaborate this into an answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181545/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-user3034944).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nilesh Rathod below is a solution

```
tvText = findViewById(R.id.tvText); 


SpannableStringBuilder spannableStringBuilder= new SpannableStringBuilder(); 
Spannable span = new SpannableString("Please press the button looking like this and then proceed .."); 
Drawable test = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_delete); 
test.setBounds(0, 0, 32,32); 
ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(test, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE); 
span.setSpan(imageSpan, span.length()-2, span.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
spannableStringBuilder.append(span); 
spannableStringBuilder.append("Second Span"); 


tvText.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
```